# SVG: Line Color

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this SVG line variable like so:

```
var c_line = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {

var c_svgLine = document.createElementNS(NS, "line");
c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x1);
c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", y1);
c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", x2);
c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", y2);
c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "line");
c_svgLine.style.stroke = color;
c_svgLine.style.width = 5;
return c_svgLine;

};
```

And the line is created as so: g, is the SVG document.

```
g.appendChild(c_line(50, 10, 100, 20,"red"));
```

in the instance of setting the colour as red, is it possible instead of using the name red but rather the raw values as the input? so something along the lines of:

```
  g.appendChild(c_line(50, 10, 100, 20,"255,60,245"));
```

I'd like to set the colour in this way because i rather not have an array filled with refined colour names I.E `["red","black","blue"....]` but generate random colours for however many lines i decided to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. use "rgb(255,60,245)" instead of "255,60,45"
2. use strokeWidth instead of width

Working Example

```js
var NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

var c_line = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {
    var c_svgLine = document.createElementNS(NS, "line");
    c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x1);
    c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", y1);
    c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", x2);
    c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", y2);
    c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "line");
    c_svgLine.style.stroke = color;
    c_svgLine.style.strokeWidth = 5;
    return c_svgLine;

};

var g = document.getElementById("g");
g.appendChild(c_line(50, 10, 100, 20, "rgb(0,60,245)"));
g.appendChild(c_line(70, 10, 150, 10, "rgb(255,60,245)"));
```

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <g id="g"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: i've done it now :)> but thanks for the reply and the brilliant answer! I'll also take onboard your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the color with rgb, rgba, and hex as seen here:

> Fill sets the color inside the object and stroke sets the color of the line drawn around the object. You can use the same css color naming schemes that you use in HTML, whether that's color names (that is red), rgb values (that is rgb(255,0,0)), hex values, rgba values, etc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes

Comment: Answers consisting primarily of links don't help the site, as the links tend to go stale over time.  Instead copy some of the relevant information from the link, then leave the link as the source of the info.

Comment: Ah that simple, i thourhg the only way to assign the strkoe was through the .style.stroke = colour; - however how i;ve done it is by     c_svgLine.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke",colour);

Comment: @Ross I updated the post with the relevant information from the source.